# Exception while integrating UIMA with Solr

Tags: xml, solr, solrj, opennlp, uima

I am trying to integrate UIMA with Solr. 
I have created the pear file(packaged and installed)- opennlp.uima.OpenNlpTextAnalyzer_pear.xml 
I am using openNLP-UIMA annotators for document analysis.

The pear(xml) file is located at my system path:D:\temp\opennlp.uima.OpenNlpTextAnalyzer 
The above path has the following directories structure consisting of :
**desc,lib,metadata,models and the pear file** itself.

content of pear file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<pearSpecifier xmlns="http://uima.apache.org/resourceSpecifier">
    <pearPath>D:\temp\opennlp.uima.OpenNlpTextAnalyzer</pearPath>
</pearSpecifier>
```

I have tested the pear file with CAS visual debugger and could see the analysis.

I referred the https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/UIMA+Integration for integration.

**I am pointing to the  path of the pear file in the AE tag.**

```
 <str name="analysisEngine">D/:temp/opennlp.uima.OpenNlpTextAnalyzer/opennlp.uima.OpenNlpTextAnalyzer_pear.xml</str>
```

But when I try to index documents,following exception is thrown:

```
2017-03-25 17:43:35.263 INFO  (qtp1389647288-18) [   x:star] o.a.s.c.S.Request [star]  webapp=/solr path=/update params={waitSearcher=true&commit=true&softCommit=false&wt=javabin&version=2} status=500 QTime=3 
2017-03-25 17:43:35.263 ERROR (qtp1389647288-18) [   x:star] o.a.s.s.HttpSolrCall null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException 
        at org.apache.solr.uima.processor.UIMAUpdateRequestProcessorFactory.getInstance(UIMAUpdateRequestProcessorFactory.java:63) 
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.UpdateRequestProcessorChain.createProcessor(UpdateRequestProcessorChain.java:216) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:55) 
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:156) 
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2036) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:657) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:464) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:257) 
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:208) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1668) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:581) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:226) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1160) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1092) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:119) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:134) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:518) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:308) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:244) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:273) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:93) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:246) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:156) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654) 
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: org.apache.uima.resource.ResourceInitializationException 
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.uima.ae.BasicAEProvider.getAE(BasicAEProvider.java:58) 
        at org.apache.solr.uima.processor.UIMAUpdateRequestProcessorFactory.getInstance(UIMAUpdateRequestProcessorFactory.java:60) 
        ... 32 more 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 
        at org.apache.uima.util.XMLInputSource.<init>(XMLInputSource.java:118) 
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.uima.ae.BasicAEProvider.getInputSource(BasicAEProvider.java:84) 
        at org.apache.lucene.analysis.uima.ae.BasicAEProvider.getAE(BasicAEProvider.java:50) 
        ... 33 more
```

I could see that its not reading the pear(xml) file, but I am not able to  find the cause for it.Am I giving the AE incorrectly?Kindly help me on the same.

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue.I was directly calling the installed pear file in Solr updateRequestHandler.Once I mapped the pear file inside a AE xml file and pointing the AE file in requesthandler solved the issue.